# How to get Uri of file to Upload file to server?

Tags: android, android-intent, cursor, uri, android-studio-3.0

I am getting audio files from specific folder and binding them on recyclerview. now i want Uri of each file so i can upload them one-by-one. i am using Cursor to get files. below is my code :

```
   Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.SIZE,MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.TITLE,android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DATA,
            MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DURATION,MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.TITLE};


    Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA + " like ? ", new String[]{"%/storage/emulated/0/Call%"},null);

    if (c != null ) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 50 && c.moveToNext(); ++i) {
            // Create a model object.
            POJO audioModel = new POJO();
            long id = c.getLong(4);
            String SIZE = c.getString(0);     // Retrieve path.
            String NAME = c.getColumnName(1); // Retrieve name.
            String PATH = c.getString(2);     // Retrieve album name.
            String DURATION = c.getString(3); // Retrieve artist name.

            Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,id);

            audioModel.setSize(SIZE);
            audioModel.setName(NAME);
            audioModel.setPath(PATH);
            audioModel.setDuration(DURATION);
            audioModel.setUri(contentUri);

            Log.d("#", String.valueOf(contentUri));


            arrayListFile.add(audioModel);
        }
        c.close();
    }
     return arrayListFile;
```

in contentUri i am getting this ( content://media/external/audio/media/0 ) . and what i want is 
   content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/xyz.mp3. how can i do ??

Comment: Are al uries ending on .../0 ? And why do you want a different uri?

Comment: `Log.d("#", String.valueOf(contentUri))`. You should log `uri.toString()`.

Comment: because it gives error while uploading to server using retrofit 2

Answer (score 0):

why do not use MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA ? the path can be also used to upload to server.

Comment: returns same Uri.. content://media/external/audio/media/46

Answer (score 0):

Please consider using (MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA must be part of your projection):

```
int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
Uri yourFileUri = Uri.parse(cursor.getString(column_index));
```